# Can I merge 2 different query (returning a single record) in a single query returning a single record?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into databse and I have the following doubt. I am using MySql.

I have two queries that both returns a single record.

Something like this:

**QUERY 1:**

```
select id_1, field_1.1, field_1.2,............., field_1.n where id=1;
```

Returning a single record containing something like:

```
field_1.1, field_1.2,...............,field_1.n
```

**QUERY 2:**

```
select username, password from settings where id=1;
```

Returning a single record containing:

```
username, password
```

I want to create a single query that merges the result of both the query in a single record, something like:

```
field_1.1, field_1.2,...............,field_1.n, username, password
```

Is it possible in some way?

Comment: @GrechkaVassili No the union creates more records

Comment: @GrechkaVassili Fields must match with SQL union. They are different in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they return just a single record and two different tables you can use:

```
select id_1, field_1.1, field_1.2,............., field_1.n,username,  
password from table1,table2 where table1.id=1 and table2.id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is easy. With one record each you'd use a cross join:

```
select q1.field_1_1, q1.field_1_2, ... q1.field_1_n, q2.username, q2.password
from (query1) q1
cross join (query2) q2;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have not relation between them you can use like this.
make sure you have same number of column in both query with same data type if you have not column you can make it blank like **" "**

```
select max(id_1),max(field_1.1)......,max(username),max(password) from 
(
select id_1, field_1.1, field_1.2,............., field_1.n,"" as username,"" as password 
 from Tabelname where id=1;
union all
select "","","","",....,"",username, password from settings where id=1
) group by username
```